# Bug reporting tool at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, bug-reporting

This would be an interesting one..

Our team's working on a project, php+jquery+postgres. We would like something good for reporting bugs. Here is the behaviours:

1. At any page, some one (mostly admin) can click some button, and the page turn into "bug-reporting" mode.
2. When the user move around the mouse, any html element will be highlighted (e.g, an inner, red, solid border).
3. When the user click the element, a floating div (at least with a text box and a submit button) pop up and the user enter some comment (e.g., please correct the title to "a right title")
4. After typing the comment, the user hit 'submit', and an ajax request (with, page url, some custom request param, and the comment + the target element) will be generated and sent to the server.

Well, I guess this could be something done in javascript, so my question is, is there any javascript lib (jQuery plugin would be the best) acts like this? I have done some search online, but with no luck..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: i think plug in will only help you do this easily. but you will have to write the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I doubt that there is anything that will do the majority of it for you but there are definitely many plugins that you will find helpful along the way.

One will almost definitely be `jQuery UI` because it might come in handy to resize elements, move them, etc.

My advice would be to think about exactly what you want the plugin to do and search for it that way.

For example, I searched "jquery plugin to edit text in element" and one of the first results was a plugin named `Jeditable` that looks very promising: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Link to `jQuery UI`: http://jqueryui.com/home